# How can I duplicate many images to black and white in a batch process?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, workflow, black-and-white, batch

I've just moved over to lightroom and need to duplicate a set of wedding photos in black and white. In aperture I used to duplicate them and then batch process them. I wondered how to go about this in lightroom, so that you don't have to do each image individually? I prefer to do them as a batch and then check them afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a secondary black & white batch and preserve original color batch in Lightroom](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/51980/how-to-create-a-secondary-black-white-batch-and-preserve-original-color-batch)

Comment: The other question is about creating duplicates and then editing each individual photo in black and white while preserving the original edits done in color. Neither the question nor the answers include any reference at all to batch converting all of the photos to B&W but merely discuss creating a set of duplicates so as not to undo the original color edits.

Comment: As someone who has at times supplied the same images to a client in both color and B&W I would encourage you to individually edit each image to optimize all of them for B&W viewing. There's a lot more to it than just reducing saturation to "0"! Brightness, contrast (especially contrast!), and applying color filters to separate two different colors that have the same tonal value in B&W are vital to best presenting an image in B&W!

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to 'batch process' in Lightroom is to choose an example image that has similar settings to other images and copy those edits to other images:

1. Edit the photo to your liking.
2. Then right click on the image, choose "Settings>Copy Settings"
3. Check all the boxes that apply.
4. Navigate to Library, then select all the images that you wish to
   include in your 'batch'. (be sure they are in similar settings/light
   so that these edits will work well)
5. Once you have chosen your images, right click and choose 'Develop
   Settings> Paste Settings"
6. Batch job done!

If you have different settings, simply repeat this process for each new setting. Collections can help you organize them.

Edit: if you need a duplicate set of each but in Black and White, add a step 4a: before applying changes, choose "Create Virtual copies". The 'originals' will be selected, you can change them to Black and White. or reselect those with a '2'.

Answer (score 0):

In light room it very simple to do a batch process, all you have to do is to shift select all the images imported with the image you have applied the editing. Then press sync button on the bottom of the editing panel ,it will ask what modifications you have to synchronize. Check the desired modifications and apply.